# Will a Windows Server Licence suffice for 2 users concurrent RDS access

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-server

We have a single PC in the office which multiple users (only 2-3 at the moment) need to access remotely through the day at the same time (and needs to be done through Remote Desktop Services since each user needs to access the full windows desktop). I have been looking into CALs and it seems that at the moment, our best bet is to go with a single device CAL, until we scale.

I tried asking a windows sales assistant a bit more about the CALs and they mentioned that buying a Windows Server license only would be enough to achieve what we want, but that contradicts a few things I have read.

All we need is the simplest solution to allow multiple users to access the PC remotely for work (including browsing, programming, running software/scripts)

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft article
[Pricing and licensing for Windows Server 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/pricing)
has this information:

| Windows Server 2019 Edition | Ideal for | Licensing model | CAL requirements[1] | Pricing Open NL ERP (USD)[3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Essentials | Small businesses with up to 25 users and 50 devices | Specialty servers (server license) | No CAL required | $501 |

The answer is positive - one Windows Server Essentials 2019 license
will suffice for up to 25 users.

You should verify whether the features of the
Windows Server Essentials 2019 are enough for your team.

Comment: @Gab - Once you move to other versions you start paying for additional cores and additional seats.  Windows Server Essentials exists for the low scale customers

Comment: @harrymc: I believe this is incorrect. Unlike the Standard version of Windows Server the Essentials edition does include normal RDS and the license stipulates remote connections should be for administration purposes only. The 25 users limit is for other services

Comment: @JamesP: That's not true. "Small businesses" don't have other services.